# How do you use Grails asset pipeline and resources plugins together?

Tags: grails, grails-2.3, grails-resources-plugin

I am trying to build a Grails 2.3.8 application using the new asset-pipeline plugin (because it is much easier to integrate with sass), but I also need to pull in a plugin (one of my own but used by other applications) that uses the resources plugin.

I tried just sticking them together but get resource not found /assets/ errors for all those defined in the resources artefact.

How do you configure these plugins to work in parallel?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Even in official docs that wrote in the Upgrade chapter.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be rephrased as "How do you use these two plugins together?"  I've not been able to find anything showing how to fix this not found /assets/ error.

Comment: Yes, question rephrased to be as Dave suggests

Comment: Also asked here and not "really" answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092183/grails-having-both-resource-plugin-and-assets-pipeline