# Grails having both Resource plugin and assets pipeline

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Hi I have my application running on grails 2.4.3 with resources plugin 1.2.8. We are planing to move to asset pipeline. Can we have both plugin working together as we will update code partially. Does anyone have any experience.

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue? Could you share your experience?

Comment: Hi @TarasKohut, As mentioned by Burt, they both use different folder and works during different life cycle (asset-pipeline during building war and resources during runtime). I just made sure that one single page is handled only by anyone (either asset or resource). For which I have to update the layout and pages using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

asset-pipeline does its work when building the war file, but resources works at runtime after deployment. So there wouldn't be anything for resources to do.

They also use different folders (asset-pipeline under `grails-app/assets`, resources under `web-app`) so by default they wouldn't even have access to the same files, right?

You should write up your experience after you get everything working - I think this would be very helpful for other developers. I'm sure the asset-pipeline developers would appreciate a docs contribution with notes on what to look for and potential gotchas, or a full tutorial if you're up for that. Or send them a link to your blog post :)

Comment: Thanks burt.. I will sure share my experience..:)

Comment: Hi Burt, I am getting following warning resource.ResourceTagLib  - Invocation of <r:resource> for a resource that apparently doesn't exist: /assets/logout-btn.png when using resource tag. When i print the result from resource I found it generate url with assets, which is behaviour from assets plugin. Further going to resource tag I found if resources plugin exist and file attr is provided it use it else linkgenerator will be used from available plugin like assets. Can you help me out....